# Unable to build project using latest version of plutus-apps using nix develop

Tags: plutus, cabal, nix, repl

When I run `cabal repl` on my project using `nix develop` I get the following error:

```
Warning: Requested index-state 2023-02-20T00:00:00Z is newer than
'hackage.haskell.org'! Falling back to older state (2023-02-19T23:48:00Z).
Warning: Requested index-state 2022-12-22T00:00:00Z is newer than
'cardano-haskell-packages'! Falling back to older state
(2022-12-13T23:38:19Z).
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: cardano-node-emulator-1.2.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] unknown package: quickcheck-contractmodel (dependency of
cardano-node-emulator)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: cardano-node-emulator,
quickcheck-contractmodel)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: cardano-node-emulator,
quickcheck-contractmodel
```

Here is my `cabal.project` file:

```
-- Custom repository for cardano haskell packages
-- See https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-haskell-packages on how to use CHaP in a Haskell project.
repository cardano-haskell-packages
  url: https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-haskell-packages
  secure: True
  root-keys:
    3e0cce471cf09815f930210f7827266fd09045445d65923e6d0238a6cd15126f
    443abb7fb497a134c343faf52f0b659bd7999bc06b7f63fa76dc99d631f9bea1
    a86a1f6ce86c449c46666bda44268677abf29b5b2d2eb5ec7af903ec2f117a82
    bcec67e8e99cabfa7764d75ad9b158d72bfacf70ca1d0ec8bc6b4406d1bf8413
    c00aae8461a256275598500ea0e187588c35a5d5d7454fb57eac18d9edb86a56
    d4a35cd3121aa00d18544bb0ac01c3e1691d618f462c46129271bccf39f7e8ee

index-state: 2023-02-20T00:00:00Z

-- See CONTRIBUTING.adoc for how to update index-state
index-state:
  , hackage.haskell.org 2023-02-20T00:00:00Z
  , cardano-haskell-packages 2022-12-22T00:00:00Z

packages: game

-- We never, ever, want this.
write-ghc-environment-files: never

-- Always build tests and benchmarks.
tests: true
benchmarks: true

-- The only sensible test display option, since it allows us to have colourized
-- 'tasty' output.
test-show-details: direct

allow-newer:
  -- cardano-ledger packages need aeson >2, the following packages have a
  -- too restictive upper bounds on aeson, so we relax them here. The hackage
  -- trustees can make a revision to these packages cabal file to solve the
  -- issue permanently.
  , ekg:aeson
  , ekg-json:aeson
  , openapi3:aeson
  , servant:aeson
  , servant-client-core:aeson
  , servant-server:aeson

constraints:
  -- cardano-prelude-0.1.0.0 needs
  , protolude <0.3.1

  -- cardano-ledger-byron-0.1.0.0 needs
  , cardano-binary <1.5.0.1

  -- plutus-core-1.0.0.1 needs
  , cardano-crypto-class >2.0.0.0
  , algebraic-graphs <0.7

  -- cardano-ledger-core-0.1.0.0 needs
  , cardano-crypto-class <2.0.0.1

  -- cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0.0.1 needs
  , cardano-prelude <0.1.0.1

  -- dbvar from cardano-wallet needs
  , io-classes <0.3.0.0

  -- newer typed-protocols need io-classes>=0.3.0.0 which is incompatible with dbvar's constraint above
  , typed-protocols==0.1.0.0

  , aeson >= 2

  , hedgehog >= 1.1

  , resource-pool <0.4.0.0

  , http2 <4.0.0

-- The plugin will typically fail when producing Haddock documentation. However,
-- in this instance you can simply tell it to defer any errors to runtime (which
-- will never happen since you're building documentation).
--
-- So, any package using 'PlutusTx.compile' in the code for which you need to
-- generate haddock documentation should use the following 'haddock-options'.
package plutus-ledger
  haddock-options: "--optghc=-fplugin-opt PlutusTx.Plugin:defer-errors"
package plutus-script-utils
  haddock-options: "--optghc=-fplugin-opt PlutusTx.Plugin:defer-errors"
package plutus-contract
  haddock-options: "--optghc=-fplugin-opt PlutusTx.Plugin:defer-errors"

-- These packages appear in our dependency tree and are very slow to build.
-- Empirically, turning off optimization shaves off ~50% build time.
-- It also mildly improves recompilation avoidance.
-- For dev work we don't care about performance so much, so this is okay.
package cardano-ledger-alonzo
  optimization: False
package ouroboros-consensus-shelley
  optimization: False
package ouroboros-consensus-cardano
  optimization: False
package cardano-api
  optimization: False
package cardano-wallet
  optimization: False
package cardano-wallet-core
  optimization: False
package cardano-wallet-cli
  optimization: False
package cardano-wallet-launcher
  optimization: False
package cardano-wallet-core-integration
  optimization: False

source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git
  tag: cc144a86
  subdir:
    cardano-node-emulator
    cardano-streaming
    doc
    freer-extras
    marconi-chain-index
    marconi-core
    marconi-sidechain
    pab-blockfrost
    plutus-chain-index-core
    plutus-chain-index
    plutus-contract
    plutus-contract-certification
    plutus-e2e-tests
    plutus-example
    plutus-ledger
    plutus-pab-executables
    plutus-pab
    plutus-script-utils
    plutus-tx-constraints
    plutus-use-cases


-- Direct dependency.
-- Compared to others, cardano-wallet doesn't bump dependencies very often.
-- Making it a good place to start when bumping dependencies.
-- As, for example, bumping the node first highly risks breaking API with the wallet.
-- Unless early bug fixes are required, this is fine as the wallet tracks stable releases of the node.
-- And it is indeed nice for plutus-apps to track stable releases of the node too.
--
-- The current version is dated 2022/08/10
source-repository-package
    type: git
    location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet
    tag: 18a931648550246695c790578d4a55ee2f10463e
    subdir:
      lib/cli
      lib/core
      lib/core-integration
      lib/dbvar
      lib/launcher
      lib/numeric
      lib/shelley
      lib/strict-non-empty-containers
      lib/test-utils
      lib/text-class

-- Direct dependency.
source-repository-package
    type: git
    location: https://github.com/Quviq/quickcheck-contractmodel
    tag: cc43f13f98c704e0d53dbdef6a98367918f8c5c1
    subdir:
      contractmodel

-- Should follow cardano-wallet.
source-repository-package
    type: git
    location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses
    tag: b7273a5d3c21f1a003595ebf1e1f79c28cd72513
    subdir:
      -- cardano-addresses-cli
      command-line
      -- cardano-addresses
      core

-- This is needed because we rely on an unreleased feature
-- https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/pull/3111
source-repository-package
    type: git
    location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger
    tag: da3e9ae10cf9ef0b805a046c84745f06643583c2
    subdir:
      eras/alonzo/impl
      eras/alonzo/test-suite
      eras/babbage/impl
      eras/babbage/test-suite
      eras/byron/chain/executable-spec
      eras/byron/crypto
      eras/byron/crypto/test
      eras/byron/ledger/executable-spec
      eras/byron/ledger/impl
      eras/byron/ledger/impl/test
      eras/shelley/impl
      eras/shelley/test-suite
      eras/shelley-ma/impl
      eras/shelley-ma/test-suite
      libs/cardano-ledger-core
      libs/cardano-ledger-pretty
      libs/cardano-protocol-tpraos
      libs/cardano-data
      libs/vector-map
      libs/set-algebra
      libs/small-steps
      libs/small-steps-test
      libs/non-integral
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share your .project file?

Comment: @FalconStakepool: I've added the `cabal.project` file.

Comment: Q1. Doesn't GHC comes with the Nix env binaries?
Q2. Did the original question got a solution?

Comment: Hi @user11782, please do not post questions as answers. If you have questions that are not answered here, feel free to open a new question where you describe the problem you have. This way the chance of getting help is a lot bigger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that a ghc must be installed globally before you try to build plutus-apps.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you have ran `cabal update` and `cabal build` before running `cabal repl` in the root folder of your project. These must be ran in the nix-shell obtained from running `nix-develop` in the plutus-apps folder and then navigating to your project directory.